# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13/11/2020' could not be parsed at index 2

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, localdate

I'm facing a problem converting from string to LocalDateTime, and adding 3 months to the current month.

This is my code:

```
String str = "13/11/2020";
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
dateTime.plusMonths(3);      //  => output: 13/02/2021
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

But when I run it I get the following exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13/11/2020' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
```

How can I fix this problem ? Many thanks

Comment: You are using a pattern `dd-MM-yyyy` to parse a `String` of the pattern `dd/MM/yyyy` resp. `dd/MM/uuuu`... Adjust the pattern in `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...)` accordingly. Index 2 is `-` in your `String` and `/` in your pattern.

Comment: Your pattern does not match your input. Why do you expect this to work? What do you think the `"dd-MM-yyyy"` is used for?

Comment: yes, so, how i can parse with format 13-11-2020 ?

Comment: "Parsing" means reading. It does not mean converting. If you want to convert, you need to first parse it with "dd/MM/yyyy" and THEN format it with "dd-MM-yyyy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues:

1. Your String is look like a `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`, it doesn't contain the time part
2. The pattern you are using is not the same format as your String it should be `dd/MM/yyyy` or `dd/MM/uuuu` and not `dd-MM-yyyy`

To parse your String you need:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"));
dateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(3);
```

---

Or if you want `LocalDateTime`, then you can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with 0 for hours, minutes and seconds:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
        .toFormatter();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
dateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(3);
```

and the result will be like this: `2021-02-13T00:00`

Note: `dateTime.plusMonths(3)` is `immutable` so to change the value you have to assign the new value to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are using the wrong format pattern. If the date string contains slashes, so should the pattern string as well: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")`.
2. If the date does not include time, then use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime`.
3. The `plusMonths` result needs to be assigned to a new variable to get the updated instance.
4. The `DateTimeFormatter` needs to be used when printing the expected result `13/02/2021`, so you can share the same formatter instance:

   ```
   String str = "13/11/2020";
   var dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
   var dateTime = LocalDate.parse(str, dateTimeFormatter);
   var newDateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(3); // => output: 13/02/2021
   System.out.println(newDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter));
   ```